# Postponing my USA travel on F1 visa for next semester

Tags: legal, f1-visas

I have an I-20 for theFall 2018 session and got my F1 visa approved. My college starts on the second week of August. Due to some family emergency, I need to postpone my travel for next semester i.e. Spring 2019.

My question is, if I defer my admission for Spring 2019 semester, and get a new I-20, will I be legally allowed to enter United states on the same F1 visa or do I need to reapply for a visa?

My F1 visa is a multiple-entry visa and is valid for the next 5 years.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Questions about long-term relocation are frequently better-answered at our sister site, [Expatriates.SE]; while we answer quite a few visa questions here, they are mostly oriented to short stays and transit.